# SQL query applying currency conversion rate

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Please help to compose an SQL query having a table with currency conversion rates that should be applied to the other table with business data, for example:

currency_rates (conversion rate is given for every beginning of the month, starting from some moment)

| currency_code | rate against USD | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CAD | 1.354 | 2022-11-01 |
| CAD | 1.3445 | 2022-12-01 |
| CAD | 1.3573 | 2023-01-01 |

business_data (fees are in USD, aggregated by name and date)

| name | sum(fee) in USD | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 92.52 | 2021-10-10 |
| bbb | 76.18 | 2022-11-11 |
| ccc | 113.79 | 2022-12-12 |
| ddd | 133.42 | 2023-02-02 |

The expected result should be the following, assuming that aggregated fee dates lay in the range of conversion rate dates (the actual result of the multiplication isn't matter here, I show x*y just to describe an idea):

| name | sum(fee) in USD * CAD conversion rate | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 92.52 * 1.354 (applied first existing rate) | 2021-10-10 |
| bbb | 76.18 * 1.354 | 2022-11-11 |
| ccc | 113.79 * 1.3445 | 2022-12-12 |
| ddd | 133.42 * 1.3573 (applied last existing rate) | 2023-02-02 |

We use Snowflake DB.
Don't hesitate to ask questions or add suggestions, thank you!

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: What is the logic that you are using between dates from business_data and currency_rates?

Comment: I truncated business_data date to have it represent the first day of the month and joined tables on dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the tables on year and month

```
select a.*, b.currency_rate --multiply as you wish
from business_data a
join currency_date b on 
     year(a.date)=year(b.date) and 
     month(a.date)=month(b.date)
```

Or more concisely,

```
select a.*, b.currency_rate --multiply as you wish
from business_data a
join currency_date b on trunc(a.date,'month')=b.date
```

As Adrian notes, my solution above doesn't account for the fact that your currency_data table does not have all the months that exist in your business_data table so let's fix that separately instead of complicating the code above.

Your sample data doesn't establish any relationship between currency_code and business data. For that reason I am going to use hardcoded 'CAD' for currency. If your business_data table has a column that ties to currency_code, you can easily modify this solution by incorporating that column in the full outer join and select statement. Also, you can switch up the order of columns inside `coalesce` to handle situations where you have both "last existing" and "first existing" rate to choose from.

```
with cte as
(select 'CAD' as currency_code, --ideally, this would a column that joins to currency data table even though your sample data doesn't indicate such a relationship
        b.rate, 
        coalesce(trunc(a.business_date, 'month'),currency_date) as currency_date
from business_data a
full outer join currency_data b on b.currency_date=trunc(a.business_date, 'month') )

select currency_code ,
       currency_date,
       coalesce(rate,
                lead(rate) ignore nulls over (partition by currency_code  order by currency_date),
                lag(rate) ignore nulls over (partition by currency_code order by currency_date)) as rate
from cte
order by currency_date
```

Comment: You are right - joining on dates is key, finally, I came to this approach today, thank you!

Comment: How does this handle the (applied last existing rate) | (applied first existing rate) scenarios?

Comment: @AdrianWhite Good catch! It doesn't. I'll add an edit later to fix the currency table separately.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[UNION ALL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query.html#union-all)

[LAG()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html)

[LEAD()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lead.html)

[COALESCE()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/coalesce.html)

[JOIN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join.html)

[BETWEEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/between.html)

```
WITH CURRENCY_RATES AS( 
      SELECT 'CAD' CURRENCY_CODE, 1.354 RATE, '2022-11-01'::DATE CURRENCY_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 'CAD' CURRENCY_CODE, 1.3445 RATE, '2022-12-01'::DATE CURRENCY_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 'CAD' CURRENCY_CODE, 1.3573 RATE, '2023-01-01'::DATE CURRENCY_DATE)

,CURRENCY_RATES_ENHANCED AS ( 
 SELECT 
  CURRENCY_CODE
    , RATE
    , CURRENCY_DATE
    , IFF(LAG(CURRENCY_DATE)OVER(PARTITION BY CURRENCY_CODE ORDER BY CURRENCY_DATE) IS NULL,'1900-01-01',CURRENCY_DATE)  CURRENCY_START_DATES  
, COALESCE(LEAD(CURRENCY_DATE)OVER(PARTITION BY CURRENCY_CODE ORDER BY CURRENCY_DATE ASC),CURRENT_DATE+999)-INTERVAL '1 SEC' CURRENCY_END_DATES  
FROM CURRENCY_RATES
 )
 ,BUSINSESS_DATA AS ( SELECT 'aaa' NAME, 92.52 FEE_IN_USD,  '2021-10-10'::DATE BUSINESS_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 'bbb' NAME, 76.18 FEE_IN_USD,  '2022-11-11'::DATE BUSINESS_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 'ccc' NAME, 113.79 FEE_IN_USD, '2022-12-12'::DATE BUSINESS_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 'ddd' NAME, 133.42 FEE_IN_USD, '2023-02-02'::DATE BUSINESS_DATE)

SELECT 
    NAME, 
    FEE_IN_USD||' * '||RATE||
    IFF(CURRENCY_START_DATES='1900-01-01'::DATE AND DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',B.BUSINESS_DATE)<>C.CURRENCY_DATE ,' (applied first existing rate)'
    ,IFF(CURRENCY_END_DATES=CURRENT_DATE+999-INTERVAL '1 SEC',' (applied last existing rate)',null)) VOLIA 
,B.BUSINESS_DATE
FROM 
    BUSINSESS_DATA B 
    JOIN CURRENCY_RATES_ENHANCED C
    ON BUSINESS_DATE BETWEEN CURRENCY_START_DATES AND CURRENCY_END_DATES                   
 ;
```